# .Net Class Declaration at Runtime

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have the following classes

CRS that is a parent class respresenting a genric Cost Recovery System. It contains properties and overridable functions

Then there are serval classes that inherit from CRS. There classes have override functions that process data specificly to a certain CRS system.

[image]

```
Public Class RDELib


Private mCRS As CRS

Public Sub New()

    VerifyServer()

    mCRS = New DriveRevenue

End Sub
```

I want to be able to set oCRM = an inheriting class in a generic way. Bases on the name of the system the clients use.

For example:

```
oCRS = New (oServer.CRSName)
```

Comment: Look up Reflection.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Look up factory patterns.  This is exactly the problem that factories solve.  (Reflection is one of the tools that can be used to set up a factory; for example, you can scan one or more assemblies for types that match a particular pattern, e.g. types that have a particular parent class.)